# groovy script to iterate through a folder and write all file names with extension to an array except the file with .txt extension

Tags: loops, groovy

I have a folder with multiple files with `.jar` extension and one file with `.txt`.

I would like to have a Groovy code that can iterate through the folder to write all the file names except that text file.

Comment: did you tried to code something? what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The following example iterates trough a given folder and prints all filenames to the console.

```
import groovy.io.FileType

File folder = new File('<a path>')

folder.eachFileRecurse FileType.FILES,  { file ->

    // do nothing if the file ends with a .txt extension
    if (!file.name.endsWith(".txt")) {
        println "Processing file ${file.absolutePath}"
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but i am only getting one file processed even though i have 100+ files

Comment: The example above only prints files with a filename ending with `.txt`. Does your directory contain files ending with that extension? Maybe you raise a new question with your specific problem and refer to this question.

Comment: @saw303 Actually it's the other way round. It excludes all the txt files and prints for all other files.